# javascript debugger stuck on break or continue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I have an older vs2005 asp.net application and occasionally the javascript debugger will break in with the "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object" popup with the options "Break" and "Continue".

The statement it breaks on is usually some piece of html that does not have any scripting, and clicking either button does nothing, the error keeps coming up until I stop the whole process.

What can I do to stop this from happening? It's very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several reboots later it suddenly started showing the proper script error location, I have no clue why it's working properly now but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "disable script debugging" in the configuration-panel of Internet Explorer. Assuming your are running Internet Explorer when you debug, of course.

On a side-note; has it occurred to you that it might be a good idea to fix this bug? :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [davekarow.com](http://kwpc.davekarow.com/dtk-DisableScriptDebuggingInIE-2010-12-17_0959.png))</sub>

Comment: Well if it broke on a script with an error I'd be more then happy to fix it, it's breaking with a highlight partially inside the src of an img tag, no script in site. I don't need to disable script debugging, I need it to stop what it's doing now, and if possible show me where the *actual* error is.

Comment: Visual Studio sometimes has a hard time parsing mixed HTML and JavaScript. In this case you can't rely on Visual Studio to tell you where the error occurred. You will have to put on your exploration hat and dive into the code yourself :)